# Rspec Testing SMTP Connection

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, smtp, actionmailer

Using RSpec, I would like to test the ability of my App to connect to my SMTP server without (necessarily) delivering any messages.

How can I open a connection (with login) to an SMTP email server and test/review the response received?

Comment: There are a couple mail mocking gems out there (like mocking mailer) that you can use, or you might consider using http://mailcatcher.me for a more system-like test.

Comment: Thanks. I think mailcatcher probably accomplishes most of what I'm hoping to cover with tests. To make my tests more granular, I was hoping to test the elements of the email creation process, including verifying the smtp settings. 

I know I can switch my smtp settings from test to smtp in the configuration, but that makes the tests more brittle than I would like, or at least a test that only works given some other setting that you have to remember to toggle.

Comment: By a matter of convention, configurations (including SMTP configurations) are declared in a file (`application.yml` for example), which is then broken down to stages (`development`, `test`, `production`...) so you don't have to toggle anything, and the test is not brittle - testing your configuration should not be a part of testing your functionality... see also http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/032-issue-3-configurable.html

Answer (score 0):

```
smtp = Net::SMTP.new 'mail.example.com', example_port
# smtp.enable_starttls_auto # uncomment this if starttls is needed
# smtp.enable_tls           # uncomment this if ssl/tls is needed but starttls is not supported
smtp.start('mydomain.example.com') do
  expect{ smtp.authenticate 'me@mydomain.example.com', 'mypassword', 'plain' }.to_not raise_error
end
```

Calling `authenticate` will raise a `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError` if the authentication fails.

Otherwise, it will return a `Net::SMTP::Response`, and calling `status` on the response will return `"235"`.